# JQuery only setting the value once in the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I'm having a slight problem. I'm taking a value from a hidden field, splitting it into an array, and setting that array as the selected options for a `<select>`

I've checked the log, and js is splitting the array properly, but for some reason it's only making the first one selected.

For example:

[Only one option selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IN8Rs.png)

#### Html

```html
<select id="relationship" multiple="multiple" name="com.Relationship" style="display:block;">
    <option value="ActiveParish">Active Parish Committee Member</option>
    <option value="AdminStaff">Administration/Staff</option>
    <option value="CommMember">Committee Member</option>
    <option value="Corporation">Corporation</option>
    <option value="Festival">Festival Committee</option>
    <option value="Friend">Friend</option>
    <option value="Music">Music Program</option>
    <option value="NewlyReg">Newly Registered</option>
    <option value="NotReg">Not Registered</option>
    <option value="Volunteer">Volunteer</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>

 <input id="relationshipstrings" name="com.RelationshipStrings" type="hidden" value="AdminStaff, CommMember, Corporation">
```

And here is my Javascript

```js
var data = document.getElementById('relationshipstrings').value

var arraydata = data.split(',');

console.log(arraydata)

$("#relationship").val(arraydata);
```

And just to verify, here is what outputs in the console :)

`Array(3)
0:"AdminStaff"
1:" CommMember"
2:" Corporation"
length:3
__proto__:Array(0)`

---

Any ideas? I had it working for a split second but I can't figure out what I did to make it stop working..

Comment: You need to trim the array items, notice the space before AdminStaff

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Wow... I feel so foolish! That did the trick! Thank you.

Comment: @NillBye please, test my snippet, is more correct than assign a value to select without selecting the proper options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to trim the array items, add this line after you set the variable:

```
arraydata = arraydata.map(item => item.trim());
```

So the whole js is now:

```
var data = document.getElementById('relationshipstrings').value
var arraydata = data.split(',');
arraydata = arraydata.map(item => item.trim()); // trim
console.log(arraydata);
$("#relationship").val(arraydata);
```

Or as @Rory McCrossan suggested, simply:

```
var arraydata = data.split(', ');
```

Comment: Or `.split(', ')`

Comment: I did think that too!

Answer (score 0):

Please, test this snippet.

You can't assign a value to `<select>` tag (well, you can, but it's a discouraged way), you must to select properly each `<option>` tag you need. So with a little code all will be perfect.

```js
var data = document.getElementById('relationshipstrings').value

var arraydata = data.split(',');

$("#relationship option").each(function(){
  if($.inArray($(this).val(), arraydata)) {
    $(this).prop('selected', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="relationship" multiple="multiple" name="com.Relationship" style="display:block;">
    <option value="ActiveParish">Active Parish Committee Member</option>
    <option value="AdminStaff">Administration/Staff</option>
    <option value="CommMember">Committee Member</option>
    <option value="Corporation">Corporation</option>
    <option value="Festival">Festival Committee</option>
    <option value="Friend">Friend</option>
    <option value="Music">Music Program</option>
    <option value="NewlyReg">Newly Registered</option>
    <option value="NotReg">Not Registered</option>
    <option value="Volunteer">Volunteer</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>

 <input id="relationshipstrings" name="com.RelationshipStrings" type="hidden" value="AdminStaff, CommMember, Corporation">
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some extra space here before the texts `value="AdminStaff, CommMember, Corporation"` so `split` will create array element along with this space

```js
var data = document.getElementById('relationshipstrings').value

var arraydata = data.split(',').map(function(item) {
  return item.trim() // to remove white space
});

var select = document.getElementById('relationship');
// looping through select options
for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
  var currOption = select.options[i].value;
  // checking if current option values is matches with any value in the 
  // array. If matches then select it
  if (arraydata.indexOf(currOption) !== -1) {
    select.options[i].selected = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="relationship" multiple="multiple" name="com.Relationship" style="display:block;">
    <option value="ActiveParish">Active Parish Committee Member</option>
    <option value="AdminStaff">Administration/Staff</option>
    <option value="CommMember">Committee Member</option>
    <option value="Corporation">Corporation</option>
    <option value="Festival">Festival Committee</option>
    <option value="Friend">Friend</option>
    <option value="Music">Music Program</option>
    <option value="NewlyReg">Newly Registered</option>
    <option value="NotReg">Not Registered</option>
    <option value="Volunteer">Volunteer</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>

<input id="relationshipstrings" name="com.RelationshipStrings" type="hidden" value="AdminStaff, CommMember, Corporation">
```